# Firestore Authentication Delete Anonymous User and Signin With Another Provider

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My App sign users anonymously automatically

```
  function onAuthStateChanged(user: FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null) {
    console.log(
      "Auth State Changed... ",
      user?.uid,
      user?.phoneNumber,
      user?.isAnonymous,
      "<<App.js"
    );
    userCurrentSet(user);
    if (!user) auth().signInAnonymously();
    if (initializing && user) setInitializing(false);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);
```

to manage anonymous accounts I want to delete the anonymous user before I sign in with the other account, something like this

```
const confirmCode = async () => {
    initilizingSet(true);
    confirm &&
      confirm.verificationId &&
      userCurrent &&
      (await userCurrent
        // -------> Trying to link the anonymous user with PhoneProvider
        .linkWithCredential(
          auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirm.verificationId, pinNumber)
        )
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e.code, "<<errCode");
          // -------> If the linking fails because the user already 
          //  has a different account, I delete the anonymous user 
          //  and login with new account
          if (e.code === "auth/credential-already-in-use") {
            userCurrent // currentuser Auth Object
              .delete() // Auth() delete current user method
              .then(() =>
                confirm.confirm(pinNumber).catch((e) => {
                  console.log(e);
                  initilizingSet(false);
                })
              )
              .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
                initilizingSet(false);
              });
          } else {
            initilizingSet(false);
          }
        }));
  };
```

my problem is with the `subscriber` kicking in and signing users anonymously again before my intentional signin, and I end up with a new anonymous user with a different id!

Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could resolve my issue is by using the `auth().deleteUser()` method from the `firebase/auth` package, the delete command will delete a user from the Firebase Authentication List, and since changes on Authentication List isn't pushed in realtime to the App no `event` is triggered, hence I got the chance to process the new Login.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems like you're [linking a provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to the existing anonymous account.

In that scenario you should **not** delete the anonymous account (as it'll just create a new account, as you see), but just link the provider. Once that process is complete, you'll have a single account, with the same UID as your original anonymous user had, but it'll no longer be an anonymous user.

Comment: Unless the user already has an account, in this case the linking will fail with `auth/credential-already-in-use`.

Comment: This is why I try linking first then if fail I sign in normally. I think Firebase should provide an option to delete the anonymous account if loging with new account, for Example the `FirebaseAuthTypes.ConfirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode: string)` confirm method should take `verificationCode` and a `config` object, when the config is set to `deleteAnonymousUser:true` it should remove the old user account, thinking of it I am actually  submitting this as a feature request now :)

Comment: You shouldn't sign the non-anymous user account in first, but just capture its credentials. Once you [link the new credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to the anonymous account, it will no longer be an anonymous account. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: This is what I am doing
(1). I am trying to link the user 
(2). if the link is failing with `"auth/credential-already-in-use"`, I try to delete the anonymous user (since I can't link it anymore and once the user sign in with another account the anonymous account is no longer of any use), then I try to sign in.

Comment: Hmm... the only other thing I can think of **before** the delete, is a change that was recently made in the SDK to protect again email enumeration attacks. This was an under the hood change, but did change some behavior. I don't have details, but if that is causing the problem you have, be sure to update to the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: I have the latest SDK! I did however found a workaround, sending the user UID to the Firebase Function and let it do the deletion with `auth().deleteUser()`, fortunately deleting a user isn't updated to the app in realtime, at least for now!